# multiple URL reads at the same time

Tags: http, matlab, asynchronous

I have a proprietary database which collects data over HTTP. For reasons beyond my control, each HTTP query can take an extended period of time, although multiple requests don't seem to slow down much the process. I would like to request many of these in some sort of a thread at the same time. Is there a method using Matlab to request multiple URLs asynchronously in Matlab?

Comment: Not terribly sure this will work for you but you can give it a read.  You'd also have to have the parallel processing toolbox.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/gads/bsc7xh9-2.html

Comment: That only works if the CPU is maxed out. It seems like there should be a way to get tasks in parallel from a server, beyond the number of cores...

Comment: Hmm, would you be able to set things up in a fashion that you could use `dfevalasync`?  (There is a synch version too of course.) http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/dfevalasync.html

Comment: While that is interesting, it doesn't seem to do what I want it to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MATLAB supports Java you can simply use Java's multi-threading tools. See for example [this tutorial](http://www.osmanoglu.org/computing/1-matlabjavamultitreading).

Answer (score 0):

You may use parfor as:

```
parfor n = 1:taskNum   
    {do urlread job here}
end
```

I have did in this way to spider google finance data to my database.

Comment: Only works up to the number of cores that you have. Ideally, I would like to do more than that.